# How to change/update/delete a property in ConfigurableEnvironment of Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring you can use inject an Environment object to read all environment properties

```
@Resource
private org.springframework.core.env.Environment environment;
```

So the question is can I programatically  change an value of some property?

The only workaround I see is to get the all MutablePropertySource that holds this property. to remove this source completely from the environment and to add a new PropertySource that contains all properties of the previous one + the changed one (or the removed one).

However this looks ugly and will be slow ;(

Comment: Why you want to change a property anyway, properties are supposed to remain constant throughout. Still you can use AOP to do this, in your advice just the parameter value if it matches the key which you want to change just return the new value.

Comment: well I want to give the ability to some "administrator" of my site to change the properties on the fly without restarting and without need to have access to the property file or the machine.

Comment: and this actually updates the value in property file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
// ConfigurableEnvironment env
MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(myObject.getKey(),
            myObject.getQuery());
propertySources
            .addFirst(new MapPropertySource("newmap", map));
```

Comment: by this u can add or update a property within environment

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer ?

Comment: when we got propertySouces from env( ConfigurableEnvironment). we are able to attach multiple properties within a new map object along with data u wanna add or update. and passing to propertySources method will allow u to add/update ur new property.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 'newmap' in the above answer by @user6631150 is the name of the property file where you want to update/add values.

Also not that this does not change the property file on disk, it only updates it in memory.

Meaning: if you have a property file newmap.properties located in C:/user/app_dir/newmap.properties and you modify it with the above code, you will not see changes in the file at this location. The changes will be in memory only. If your application restarts, no changes will be at the said location.

Comment: Yes but this is what I was looking long time ago :D

Comment: I a little puzzled because your answer is continuing the 1st answer. It is clearly useful (I've seen people wondering about this) but it could almost be a comment. I am not sure what should be recommended: improving the 1st answer, commenting or including the code of the 1st in your answer.

Comment: @mgibson: Juh_ is right. The right way to do this would be adding your text to the answer of user6631150 and removing this answer. This answer has no value in itself, but is a good improvement to the answer of user6631150.