# How can I change a property in spring environment?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using the spring Environment Bean in my application to get the application configuration properties.
I want to change the value of a property in the spring Environment from java code without restarting the application server. How can I do that?

```
@Service
public void MyService {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public void doSomething(){
        String value = environment.getProperty("myproperty");
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Environment` implementation that you will get by default in the Spring context is actually an instance of [StandardEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html).

`StandardEnvironment` implements [ConfigurableEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html), so if you inject a `ConfigurableEnvironment` instead of the super interface you will be able to make alterations at runtime.

```
@Service
public void MyService {
    @Autowired private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;
```

Comment: My environment variable is populated from a yml. Will this approach also write to the yml file or only the variable?

Comment: you should add code to actually add/change properties. The doc isn't crystal clear I think.

Comment: see this for code to add properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654266/1206998