# Update the application property in Java

Tags: java, spring

My java application has following properties defined in my  application.property file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**mysystemName**/;instance=mydb;domain=DHC;trusted=true;
```

Is it  possible to read the machine name and add it in the spring.data source.url? The `mysystemName` should be dynamically loaded.

Any method for reading and updating value run time? I am looking for something like below.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://${someMachineNameFromCode}/;instance=mydb;domain=DHC;trusted=true;
```

I don't want to read the properties and format and write back. I am looking for some expressions which I can use directly inside `application.properties`.

Comment: A changing datasource url seems strange so I need to ask why you would want to do something like that.

Comment: Anyhow: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886567/how-can-i-change-a-property-in-spring-environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change a property in spring environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886567/how-can-i-change-a-property-in-spring-environment)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways of changing Spring properties during runtime. **EnvironmentPostProcessor** and **ApplicationListener** are among them. Here, I am going to include an example of EnvironmentPostProcessor.

1. Create a custom `EnvironmentPostProcessor` as shown below.
2. The `CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor` class looks up *application configuration propertie*s.
3. If it finds any property with a value which contains a substring pattern matching `"%%mysystemName%%"`, it replaces it with the server hostname.
4. The modified properties are stored in a placeholder.
5. If the modified properties placed holder is not empty, it is added at the beginning of all other properties.
6. You also have to register the class in `META-INF/spring.factories`.

#### spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
  com.basaki.config.CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

#### application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://%%mysystemName%%/;instance=mydb;domain=DHC;trusted=true;
```

#### CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor.java

```
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private static final String APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES =
            "applicationConfigurationProperties";

    private static final String SYSTEM_PATTERN = "%%mysystemName%%";

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
            ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
            SpringApplication springApplication) {

        MutablePropertySources sources = environment.getPropertySources();
        Properties modifiedProps = new Properties();

        if (sources.contains(APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES)) {
            PropertySource<?> source = sources.get(
                    APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES);
            if (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
                EnumerablePropertySource target =
                        (EnumerablePropertySource) source;
                for (String name : target.getPropertyNames()) {
                    Object value = target.getProperty(name);
                    if (value instanceof String) {
                        if (((String) value).contains(SYSTEM_PATTERN)) {
                            try {
                                String newValue = ((String) value).replaceAll(SYSTEM_PATTERN,
                                        hostname());
                                modifiedProps.put(name, newValue);
                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!modifiedProps.isEmpty()) {
            sources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("customAppProperties",
                    modifiedProps));
        }
    }

    public String hostname() throws UnknownHostException {
        String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        int index = hostName.indexOf(".local");
        hostName = (index > 0) ? hostName.substring(0, index) : hostName;
        return hostName;
    }
}
```