# change only one property in application.property spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application.property file in project

```
username=stm-bce93d@nurego.com
password=123456
baseId=4e1c-a459-0885d5849686
serviceId=49ca-a348-38ef3dc89a16
```

and when I run my test I want to change only password field and get it from system variable.
how can I change it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736711/update-the-application-property-in-java

Comment: maybe you can see this;
[change property at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37052857/8311273)

Comment: If you're using `@SpringBootTest`, there's an annotation parameter to supply properties. (Note that you shouldn't be putting credentials into your source code anyway; use environment variables at runtime or a more comprehensive "secrets" solution like Vault or your deployment environment's management tools.)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use profiles. Enabling the `test` profile you can define a different value in `application-test.properties`, which would look something like that

```
username=stm-bce93d@nurego.com
password=${PWD}
baseId=4e1c-a459-0885d5849686
serviceId=49ca-a348-38ef3dc89a16
```

PWD is an environment variable