# How to get the SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT in a testpropertysource additional properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am writing a test that uses `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`, but I need to use this port value in a property used by some external bean (i.e. that I cannot change).

I tried using `{local.server.port}`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "externalProp.accessUrl=http://localhost:{local.server.port}}/foo"
})
public class MyTest {
    ...
}
```

but I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'local.server.port'`

How can I do that?

Comment: doesn't `"externalProp.accessUrl=/foo"` work?

Comment: Well this property is supposed to get the full url. `localhost:local.server.port` is only something I provide in this test. In a real execution it should be the url of an external api.

Comment: It think you have some typos: missing `$`, extra `}`.  I used `"externalProp.accessUrl=http://localhost:${local.server.port}/foo"` and I was able to get a URL with `@Value("${externalProp.accessUrl}")`

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried with ${local.server.port}? Otherwise, you can set property **externalProp.accessUrl** by using System.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private static int randomServerPort;


    @Before
    public void setUp(){

 System.setProperty("externalProp.accessUrl","http://localhost:"+randomServerPort+"/foo");
   }
}
```

Comment: environment hasn't a `setProperty` method (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654266/1206998). Also randomServerPort is not initialized correctly if it is static (value is set to 0).

Comment: Sorry my bad, you can set by System object. Corrected my answer.